# Can I recast the memory in a std::vector to a completely different type?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Vector3
{
    float data[3];
}
```

I have another 3rd party library which reads the contents of a file, and loads the data into a `vector<float>`, which is passed to it by reference:

```
void ThirdPartyReadData(std::string fileName, std::vector<float> &vecFloat);
```

I need to give that data to another 3rd party function, which wants the data in the form of `vector<Vector3>`:

```
void ThirdPartyUseData(std::vector<Vector3> &vecVector3);
```

The obvious solution to this is to simply copy all of the data out of the `vector<float>` into the `vector<Vector3>`, but it seems like a waste. That memory is already in exactly the format is would be in when copied to the `vector<Vector3>`. I wonder if there is some way to re-construct the original `vector<float>` as a `vector<Vector3>`, without freeing all of that memory?

Comment: No, there isn't, sorry, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @LouisGo how is that a problem for `{ std::vector<float> floats; ThirdPartyReadData("file", floats); std::vector<Vector3> vectors = someMagic(floats); ThirdPartyUseData(vectors); }`

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to avoid copying when converting from `std::vector<float>` to `std::vector<Vector3>`.

At least one of the third party libraries would have to be changed in order to avoid copying. Either read the file directly onto `std::vector<Vector3>` by changing the reader, or change the user to accept a `std::vector<float>`. Or even better, use iterators or ranges to make the library more generally useful.

Comment: What if I did a "Placement new" to construct a new vector right on top of the old one?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet You cannot "placement new" to replace a vector. Placement new should only be used on raw memory from operator new, or at most on memory with trivial objects (latter has some technicalities in language rules that are probably not a problem in practice). Vector is non-trivial.